# How do you call a function every time a randomly timed function is called using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that's being called at random times by utilizing setTimeout() and a randomly generated number.

```
 function fireAtRandomTimes(){
   dostuff;
   setTimeout(fireAtRandomTimes, Math.random() * 20000);
 }
```

I want to call a function every time fireAtRandomTimes() is finished running without manipulating the fireAtRandomTimes() function.

jQuery's $.when and $.then seem close to what I'm looking for but the problem is each one of these methods will only be executed once.

```
$.when( fireAtRandomTimes() ).then(function() {
   console.log('when');
   });
```

I've also attempted creating a function that utilizes $.when and invoking itself at the end and this resulted in an infinite loop.

How can I use jQuery to call a function every time a randomly timed function is finished running?

Comment: *without manipulating the fireAtRandomTimes() function.* If `fireAtRandomTimes` cannot be changed, it's impossible, unless you monkeypatch `setTimeout`, which is an even worse idea

Comment: @CertainPerformance
I see. Thank you for the input, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

What prevents you from modifying `fireAtRandomTimes()`? More context explaining why you're trying to do this might reveal some other solutions are actually possible (proxies, wrapping, etc).

If you have control of `fireAtRandomTimes()`, it can be accomplished with a one-time modification. (So you could reuse `fireAtRandomTimes()` in multiple projects without further modification.) You just need to add a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) like this:

```
function fireAtRandomTimes(){
   window.dispatchEvent(new Event('customEvent'));
   setTimeout(fireAtRandomTimes, Math.random() * 20000);
 }

window.addEventListener('customEvent', function(e) {
    console.log('Custom Event')
});
```